# how do i solve Enabled Item Pipeline: []?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy script to scrape a website. The code block is correct but when I run it, it gives me an empty return. I tried to check logs and found `2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: []` . I don't know if it's why my script is not returning any results.

Also I recently formatted my pc and reinstalled python and it's libraries back, also reinstalled VS code. I don't know if am missing something in the settings or wherever.

Here's my script

```
  import scrapy

  class TruckspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       name = 'truckspider'
       allowed_domains = ['www.quicktransportsolutions.com']
       start_urls = ['https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/carrier/usa-trucking-companies.php']

       def parse(self, response):
         containers = response.css('[class="col-md-4 column"]')
         for container in containers:
            yield {
                'name': container.css('a::text').get()}
```

Here is my log

```
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.7.1 started (bot: truckscraper2)
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, 
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022), cryptography 39.0.0, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'truckscraper2',
'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'truckscraper2.spiders',
'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
'SPIDER_MODULES': ['truckscraper2.spiders'],
'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: 
twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: 
asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 27ed26758870e117
2023-02-02 08:32:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-02-02 08:32:54 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-02-02 08:32:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/robots.txt> from <GET http://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/robots.txt>
2023-02-02 08:32:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-02-02 08:32:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/> from <GET http://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/>
2023-02-02 08:32:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/> (referer: None)
2023-02-02 08:32:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-02 08:32:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 944,
'downloader/request_count': 4,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
'downloader/response_bytes': 8482,
'downloader/response_count': 4,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.496689,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2, 7, 32, 57, 227109),
'httpcompression/response_bytes': 21965,
'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
'log_count/INFO': 10,
'response_received_count': 2,
'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2, 7, 32, 54, 730420)}
2023-02-02 08:32:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

please help me get my scrapy working again and extracting informations as usual. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got the answer to this. I gave my pc access to this file `2023-02-02 10:54:17 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2733195998640 on C:\Users\ChiNedu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock` from my AppData folder and every other thing worked perfectly like a magic.

Hope this helps some one out there someday.